# Why Pyppeteer Python is unable to load extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pyppeteer

I use instead of chromium real browser called Brave.

Pyppeteer is however not able to load any extension from any profile I do which is I think a big problem, I have C# or .NET puppeteer or puppeteersharp and I have no issue at all so I checked the PyPpeteer API docs and I did all they wrote and still I stuck.

My code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from pystyle import *
import os, sys, time, random, threading, requests, json, base64
from html5lib import *
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer_stealth import stealth
from pystyle import Colorate, Colors, Write, Add, Center, System
from pyppeteer.dialog import Dialog
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, Dict, List, Optional, Union

async def browser_with_extensions():
    _extention1_path = "C:\Users\PC_USER\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Extensions\ofjjanaennfbgpccfpbghnmblpdblbef\1.3_0"

    _executablePath = "C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe"
    _userDataDir = "C:\Users\PC_USER\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data"

    url = ""
    args = [
            '--disable-extensions-except={}'.format(_extention1_path),
            '--load-extensions={}'.format(_extention1_path),
            '--enable-automation',
            '--start-maximized',
            '--hide-scrollbars',
            '--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash',
            '--mute-audio',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu'
    ]

    browser = await launch({
        'headless': False,
        'slowMo': 5,
        'options': {'args': args}, 
        'executablePath': _executablePath,
        'userDataDir': _userDataDir,
        'defaultViewport': None
    })

    page = await browser.newPage()
    await stealth(page)
    await page.goto(url,  {'waitUntil' : 'domcontentloaded'})
```

Answer (score 1):

if it helps to someone here is my code I solve it:

```
  import asyncio
    from pyppeteer import launch
    from pyppeteer_stealth import stealth
    
_extention2_path = open("./Data/extentions/extention_path2.txt", "r").read().rstrip()
_extention3_path = open("./Data/extentions/extention_path3.txt", "r").read().rstrip()
_extention4_path = open("./Data/extentions/extention_path4.txt", "r").read().rstrip()
_extention5_path = open("./Data/extentions/extention_path5.txt", "r").read().rstrip()
_browserPath = open("./Data/browserPath.txt", "r").read().rstrip()
_browserUserData = open("./Data/browserUserData.txt", "r").read().rstrip()
        
        args = [
                    '--load-extension={}'.format(_extention2_path),
                    '--load-extension={}'.format(_extention3_path),
                    '--load-extension={}'.format(_extention4_path),
                    '--load-extension={}'.format(_extention5_path),
                    '--ignore-certificate-errors',
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--disable-notifications',
                    '--start-maximized'
                ]
        browser = await launch({
                                'headless': False,
                                'slowMo': randomWait,
                                'options': {'args': args}, 
                                'executablePath': _browserPath,
                                'userDataDir': _browserUserData,
                                'ignoreDefaultArgs': ["--disable-extensions", "--enable-automation"],
                                'defaultViewport': None
                })
    
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await stealth(page)
```

PS: BTW this PyPpeteer or classic Puppeteer or even Sharp have very very far away to be perfect, since you can't even load context incognito with extentions and real browser I'm using Brave btw, also the Alerts and Dialogs from sites like spotify or others doesnt applies to dialog.dissmiss class at all so I will find other solution because this is not fun to code with puppeteer and I think dev team during covid19 abbondoned this because too many issues on GitHub as well.
Cheers